# Getting error while building Virtual Raster

Tags: qgis, raster

The following layers were not correctly generated.

- C:/Users/Shreelakshmi C R/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_45117873c29b4e15a154e8405acddbfb/99d397046dcf4d578d7fc4ade40e9ba8/OUTPUT.vrt

You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: I would not recommend to use paths with spaces. Sometimes they work, sometimes not.

Comment: This looks like a generic error message that in theory could have been caused by anything. As the message says, the output of the log messages panel would probably clarify which error it was.

Answer (score 1):

In Raster->Build Virtual Raster->parameters->input layers, the layers were not selected.
Check the input layers on and the error is resolved.